# File not found error using Ionic native File Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am trying to implement a simple user signup where the user has the option to upload a profile image.

I am using the Ionic native crop plugin to crop the image. This returns a URI that I am going to use to read the file from cache directory using the native file plugin. Now the problem is that `file.readAsDataURL()` returns a file not found error.

Here is my code:

```
addFromGallery(){
 this.camera.getPicture(this.galleryOptions)
  .then((fileUri) => {
      // Modify fileUri format, may not always be necessary
      fileUri = 'file://' + fileUri;
      /* Using cordova-plugin-crop starts here */
      return this.crop.crop(fileUri, { quality: 100 });
  }).then((path) => {
    this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.cacheDirectory, "a.txt")
      .then(function (success) {
        console.log("SUCESS", success);
        // success
      }, function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR', error);
        // error
      });
  })
}
```

I have consoled `this.file.cacheDirectory` and it returns the correct path where a.txt is located (file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.myapp191974/cache/) yet `file.readAsDataURL()` can't find it.

I am testing on a real device running Android Nougat.

Comment: Sometime back when i tried to do the same, i gotta know that cache directory cant be read due permission issue, then i switched to externalDataDirectory

Comment: It does not look like a permissions issue since Crop plugin is able to write to cache directory. I have checked cache directory for the app by using file manager and  i can see croped images there.

Comment: Could you try out once in datadirectory just to isolate the issue?

Comment: Yes, i'll try that, can't do it right now, and let you know. Thank you bro.

Comment: Welcome. Keep us posted

Comment: Did you manage to fix this, @AbdulQadeer?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.file.cacheDirectory.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
```